# Azure Functions - Unable to import other python modules in called scripts

Tags: python, python-3.x, azure, azure-functions

I have created a simple HTTP trigger-based azure function in python which is calling another python script to create a sample file in azure data lake gen 1. My solution structure is given below: -

[image]

Requirements.txt contains the following imports: -

- azure-functions
- azure-mgmt-resource
- azure-mgmt-datalake-store
- azure-datalake-store

**init.py**

```
import logging, os, sys

import azure.functions as func
import json

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    name = req.params.get('name')
    if not name:
        try:
            req_body = req.get_json()
        except ValueError:
            pass
        else:         
            name = req_body.get('name')

    if name:
        full_path_to_script = os.path.join(os.path.dirname( __file__ ) + '/Test.py')
        logging.info(f"Path: - {full_path_to_script}")
        os.system(f"python {full_path_to_script}")
        return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello {name}!")
    else:
        return func.HttpResponse(
             "Please pass a name on the query string or in the request body",
             status_code=400
        )
```

**Test.py**

```
import json
from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread

directoryId = ''
applicationKey = ''
applicationId = ''
adlsCredentials = lib.auth(tenant_id = directoryId, client_secret = applicationKey, client_id = applicationId)
adlsClient = core.AzureDLFileSystem(adlsCredentials, store_name = '')

with adlsClient.open('stage1/largeFiles/TestFile.json', 'rb') as input_file:
    data = json.load(input_file)
    with adlsClient.open('stage1/largeFiles/Result.json', 'wb') as responseFile:
        responseFile.write(data)
```

Test.py is failing with an error that **no module found azure.datalake.store**
Why other required modules are not working for Test.py since it is inside the same directory?

[image]

pip freeze output: -

```
adal==1.2.2
azure-common==1.1.23
azure-datalake-store==0.0.48
azure-functions==1.0.4
azure-mgmt-datalake-nspkg==3.0.1
azure-mgmt-datalake-store==0.5.0
azure-mgmt-nspkg==3.0.2
azure-mgmt-resource==6.0.0
azure-nspkg==3.0.2
certifi==2019.9.11
cffi==1.13.2
chardet==3.0.4
cryptography==2.8
idna==2.8
isodate==0.6.0
msrest==0.6.10
msrestazure==0.6.2
oauthlib==3.1.0
pycparser==2.19
PyJWT==1.7.1
python-dateutil==2.8.1
requests==2.22.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
six==1.13.0
urllib3==1.25.6
```

Comment: It seems you haven't import "azure.datalake.store", your code just import some parts(core, lib, multithread) of "azure.datalake.store". Could you please try to add a line "import azure.datalake.store" in your "Test.py" ?

Comment: I have tried that. No luck. Same error - "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'azure'"

Comment: Hi TechGuru, may I know if the screenshot contains all your code ? And does your code run successful in local ?

Comment: The above-given code is complete. It works fine in local.

Comment: I test it with your code just now and it works fine. The only difference is I run the command "pip freeze > requirements.txt" in "TERMINAL" to generate the "requirements.txt" and then deploy to Azure.

Comment: Are you using python 3.6.8 version? I am still getting the same issue.

Comment: Yes, the same version to your python. As your code run successful in local, you can have a try with the command "func azure functionapp publish <APP_NAME> --build local" in "TERMINAL" in VS code to deploy your function to Azure. After running this command, project dependencies are read from the requirements.txt file and those dependent packages are downloaded and installed locally. Project files and dependencies are deployed from your local computer to Azure. This results in a larger deployment package being uploaded to Azure and will not lose any module. Please have a try.

Comment: @HuryShen I have tried this also. But, having no luck. I think azure-functions-core-tools is having some problems. Here are the logs for OUTPUT: -
Build orchestrated by Microsoft Oryx, https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx
You can report issues at https://github.com/Microsoft/Oryx/issues
testpython1234: Warning: An outdated version of python was detected (3.6.9). Consider updating.\nVersions supported by Oryx: https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx
Source directory     : /tmp/zipdeploy/extracted
 Destination directory: /home/site/wwwroot
 Python Version: /opt/python/3.6.9/bin/python3

Comment: @TechGuru Can you share the output of `pip freeze` in your question?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Added. Please check it.

Comment: Have you tried setting up a Python virtual environment and testing in there?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Yes, I have tested and it working fine. It is not working in azure.

Comment: Hi @TechGuru, just for double check. May I know if you removed the line "from azure.datalake.store import core, lib, multithread" when you add the line "import azure.datalake.store" as I mentioned at the begining of my comments ? Since one user combine both of these two lines and works fine in another case.

Comment: @HuryShen I removed the line. I am trying by removing node from my system. I will re-install everything and then give it a try,

Comment: Hi TechGuru, may I know if your problem was solved ?

Comment: @HuryShen I tried everything and nothing is working. I am not sure why it is working in local. It should give the same error as in Azure.

Answer (score 0):

### Problem

`os.system(f"python {full_path_to_script}")` from your functions project is causing the issue.

Azure Functions Runtime sets up the environment, along with modifying process level variables like `os.path` so that your function can load any dependencies you may have. When you create a sub-process like that, not all information will flow through. Additionally, you will face issues with logging -- logs from `test.py` would not show up properly unless explicitly handled.

Importing works locally because you have all your `requirements.txt` modules installed and available to `test.py`. This is not the case in Azure. After remotely building as part of publish, your modules are included as part of your code package published. It's not "installed" globally in the Azure environment per se.

### Solution

You shouldn't have to run your script like that. In the example above, you could import your `test.py` from your `__init__.py` file, and that should behave like it was called `python test.py` (at least in the case above). Is there a reason you'd want to do `python test.py` in a sub-process over importing it?

Here's the official guide on how you'd want to structure your app to import shared code -- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-python#folder-structure

**Side-Note**

I think once you get through the `import` issue, you may also face problems with `adlsClient.open('stage1/largeFiles/TestFile.json', 'rb')`. We recommend following the developer guide above to structure your project and using `__file__` to get the absolute path ([reference](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-python-worker/issues/340#issuecomment-467619721)).

For example --

```
import pathlib
with open(pathlib.Path(__file__).parent / 'stage1' / 'largeFiles' /' TestFile.json'):
....
```

---

Now, if you really want to make `os.system(f"python {full_path_to_script}")` work, we have workarounds to the import issue. But, I'd rather not recommend such approach unless you have a really compelling need for it. :)

Comment: The reason behind using 'python test.py' is to have a dynamic script calling. Script name could be xyz depending on the parameters. adlsclient.open should not have any issue since the path is related to Azure DataLake, not local/Azure.

Comment: You should be able to dynamically import the module, if you'd like, using `importlib.import_module(<name>)`. If that doesn't work for you, please let me know. See - https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.import_module

Comment: @TechGuru, please let us know if that works for you, or if you have any questions about it.

Comment: unfortunately, it is not working. The above issue is just a part of the POC of a huge application that is currently running inside Kubernetes containers. I wanted to migrate it to Azure functions. I am restructuring my code and re-writing from scratch keeping limitations in mind. Thanks for your help. I will post the answer once this will be done.